# empty view when displaying WebView (WebGL an Video) inside 3D app

Tags: android, webview, opengl-es-2.0, gvr-android-sdk

I inserted a webview in my 3D Game. I can manage to retrieve URL and display it on a canvas and texture it in my 3D rendering.

Everything work fine except from the Video the WebGL and Threeje rendering.

For this 3 case I cannot see anything except the 2 canvas from threeJS (the frame canvas information) and ( the check box option)

In all these 3 case the view where WebGL or video are empty should be rendered are empty.

For the video I found out that I can see the image only when I touch the seekbar under the play button and audio button.

So it looks like the rendering view seems to be hidden or not visible or something else.

So I tried to get the view rendered by WebView to check the status. But WebView only got One View and it is not possible to get the elements view inside to check it.

So I am not sure if the problem come from the view status or from conflict with the 3D environment.

So I would like to know if someone have an idea about the problem. Or if someone could tell me how to retrieve the detailed view from webview, if it is possible.

NEW INFORMATION

I think that the problem could come from:

1. running WEBGL(opengl 1.4) from WebView inside GvrActivity(OpenGL es 2)
   may cause a conflict when rendering both Android OpenGL at same time.
2. Concerning the media and audio. I am also running voice recognition
   (Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) and mediaplayer to watch loader video.

LAST TESTING:

So if I run WebView in another activity everything is fine. The problem is that I would like to retrieve an access to this activity to get the Webview VIEW displayed in the main activity layout.

Is that possible?

LAST TESTING:

Changing Context Activity starting WebView does not resolve the problem.
So I found out that if I attach the WebView to the getWindow().addContentView
there is no problem But is if I add the view to MyGLSurfaceView extends GvrView
i got the problem. An I think it is because I already use the Media player to render video To 3D mesh and OpenGL to draw The 3D scene. But I am not sure of that.

LAST TESTING : (je rame (french expression))

I try everything. I think I did. And I think that after 3 weeks I start to be out of resources.

Concerning the audio from the webview I am sure a get in conflict with the voice recognition mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); Which I think is use by Webview because I can use it displaying video inside canvas in 3D OpenglES.

Concerning the video from Webview in need to touch The progression bar to see something. But as Webview is a black box. No way to get the progress bar view and act on it.

Concerning WebGL and threeJS. I can display web text and image but nothing related to opengl, white display but not transparent, because a set transparency to check. Can only be displayed outside of the OPenGL environment and outside of Surface and surfacetexture.

Concerning Webview: Only one view output. So all the view rendering seems to be done internally using tag parser for position and canvas construction, so no view may be used. But is I consider that the ourput view of Webview is a complete bitmap of all the tag canvas (that I my one interpretation it is easy to use tag tree for rendering fast access and easy structured design information structure). But I am wondering in this case why WebGL and ThreeJs cannot be copied using  surfacetexture.updateTexImage() if webview output is a bitmap canvas.

Because everything are 2D canvas when they are displayed inside view.

So 3 week trying to find answer. I hope that someone will find it.
Because I was planing to do an ART gallery in VR where anyone could watch video or 3D ART. For the video and 360 video I could make it but not for WebGL and ThreeJS.

3D inside 3D is the top in ART technology. Imagine that you could go in any 3D shop or Accessing Web URL to any Video of artiste or whatever. The last thing is possible but not the WEGgl and TrheeJS. Watching YouTube 360 VR is easy a can make it, it works very well with voice command, just Hack to get the download address, easy. Why to block when the best is to be open and let the imagination create the tomorrow tools?

So I give up and go back to my OPenCL recognition application which is nearly finished. Form recognition could be great new tools.

By the way. Do not hesitate to ask me for my APK if you want to check by yourself. Stack Overflow are allowed to contact me as they got my email address.

LAST TEST (07/07/2020)

So i think I understood the problem concerning the non accessibility to the Video and webgL display. The first intention concerning Video is surely the fact that they wanted to avoid the ability to copy the video and the problem of optimization of the rendering. Concerning WebGL their is no need to avoid the copying. But it need to be optimized to avoid to redraw the all webview picture when only one part is modified. So it look like the rendering of video and webGL is done in another thread and that the rendering is independent of the other HTML TAG.

Some said that because it is done in other thread it is not possible to access it. Which is false, because the canvas where the rendering is done must be accessible if we want it to be accessible. It is just a bitmap for the video and a frame buffer(viewport) for webGL. I agree that is done by GPU card and not by software but the resulting canvas(rectangle) could be accessible because at the end it is displayed. The problem is that it is not part anymore of the WebView final view, they just send the position where the display must be done to the GPU as viewport coordinate.

So when I try to SurfaceTexture.updateTexImage() I just get some part of the web page, no video and no webgl.

Here is an example to anderstand:
if you load this URL "https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/webgl-2d-triangle-with-position-for-color.html" and look at the code in you browser.
I can see and manipulate the slider without problem but the GL result is not visible. Because the canvas is an openGL context and it is process by the GPU and directly copy to the final frame buffer at the right place but it is not part of the Webview final view, which is unique. For the video if a can get the slider i can have some picture but i have to get it and check is modification, hard work and i am not really interested by video, found other way to watch it in OpenGL .

So I think that Android could make an effort to try to give the access to the Canvas for webgl rendering. And find a way to give an access to it inside WebView. 3D inside 3D is already 4 dimension. Could be good. But not available at the moment. But it will.

I will look at it, just by curiosity. But no chance I think.

Answer (score 0):

here is the only answer i have found :

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/3wrULcul8lw

today (24/09/2020) i read this :

DRM-protected video can be presented only on an overlay plane. Video players that support protected content must be implemented with SurfaceView. Software running on unprotected hardware can't read or write the buffer; hardware-protected paths must appear on the Hardware Composer overlay (that is, protected videos disappear from the display if Hardware Composer switches to OpenGL ES composition).

30/09/2020 :
i am able to see and manipulate WebGl display using Surface.lockHardwareCanvas but a looze the focus during manipulation and sometimes it does not work, little probleme ;)).
But using lockHardwareCanvas  when a display youtube web page with video or without, everything is frezzing, cannot udtate the view neither scroll it.
Mais ça avance ;))

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

1. WebGL and Jthree can be display using Surface.lockHardwareCanvas
2. the problem is using Surface.lockHardwareCanvas with htlm other than accelerated View. In this case there is no frame to listen so no refreshing of the view. so must be done in other way.
3. concerning the OpenGL,WebGL and Jthree. It depends on the application somme are not weel displayed for many reason (no GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, canvas not facteur of 2, and bad view size). And the problem is that there is no new onframeavailable so need to find other way to refresh the view.

It took quite a long time to anderstand but it is working even in GVRActivity ;))

Regards.